# Passing an Associative array into another associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

apologies if this is a simple fix - I'm having trouble passing a few arrays in PHP.
I have two arrays setup eg:

```
$person = array(
            'height' => 100,
            'build'  => "average",
            'waist'  => 38,
            );

$hobbies = array(
            'climbing' => true,
            'skiing'   => false,
            'waist'    => 38,
            );
```

now if I perform a print_r() on these arrays they return results as expected.I then insert the 2 arrays into a new array as seen below:

```
$total = array($person, $hobbies);
```

using print_r once again returns a new array containing both arrays but it is not associative. However if I try to do the following:

```
$total = array(
                'person'   <= $person,
                'hobbies'  <= $hobbies,
               );
```

and I perform a print_r on $total using the code above I am not seeing both arrays with associations. ^ the above data is just an example data but identical in structure in my real app, I get returned the following result:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 )
```

Once again apologies if I am being extremely thick - which I have a feeling I am.

Comment: Are you trying to merge the two arrays into a single array? I'm confused.

Comment: no I want to try and achieve the following structure
Array ( [person] (*person_data*) [hobbies] => (*hobby data*) ), in reality I am creating a quiz app and need both the question and answer options within one array but separate - so I can loop around the answer options and do cool stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array assignments are the wrong way round: `'person' <= $person` should be `'person' => $person`.

```
// Wrong
$total = array(
  'person' <= $person,
  'hobbies' <= $hobbies,
);

// Right
$total = array(
  'person' => $person,
  'hobbies' => $hobbies,
);
```

Comment: ^^ thankyou, I knew it would be something stupid I just couldn't spot it sorry guys, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want the `$total` array to have `person` and `hobbies` keys for the sub-arrays. If so, simply do this:

```
$total = array("person" => $person, "hobbies" => $hobbies);
```

Example with output: http://3v4l.org/5U5Hh

Comment: Oh, that's what he meant!

Comment: thanks - sorry me being really slow putting the assignment operators the wrong way around - its been a long day ;)

Comment: will do - theres a time you have to wait before you can accept - I will do ASAP though :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use array_merge, if you want to merge both array into a new array.

```
$result = array_merge($person, $hobbies);
```